# How to insert two columns (first one with same value) to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is simple example explaining what I want. I need to add column from first dataframe to other:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon',
                               'Parrot', 'Parrot'],
                    'Max Speed': [380., 370., 24., 26.]})

outlets = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['mac', 'x'])

outlets = outlets.append({'mac' : 1, 'x' : [*df.Animal]}, ignore_index=True)
outlets
```

Output is :

```
   mac       x
0   1   [Falcon, Falcon, Parrot, Parrot]
```

But what I really want is:

```
   mac       x
0   1      Falcon
1   1      Falcon
2   1      Parrot
3   1      Parrot
```

Please tell me how can I make what I want...

Comment: `outlets.explode("x")`?

Comment: Why are you creating the DataFrame, and then appending, in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for append [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html), you can do merge two dataframes like this:

**Less Efficient:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon',
                               'Parrot', 'Parrot'],
                    'Max Speed': [380., 370., 24., 26.]})

outlets = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['mac', 'x'])

for animal in [*df.Animal]:
    outlets = outlets.append({'mac': 1,'x': animal}, ignore_index=True)
print(outlets)
```

**More Efficient:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon',
                               'Parrot', 'Parrot'],
                    'Max Speed': [380., 370., 24., 26.]})


outlets = pd.concat(
    [pd.DataFrame([[1, animal]], columns=['mac', 'x']) for animal in [*df.Animal]],
    ignore_index=True)
print(outlets)
```

**Output:**

```
Less efficient:
   mac       x
0    1  Falcon
1    1  Falcon
2    1  Parrot
3    1  Parrot

More efficient:
  mac       x
0   1  Falcon
1   1  Falcon
2   1  Parrot
3   1  Parrot
```